# What is the highest major version number possible?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, version-history, version, boundaries

We have documents that are updated automatically in SharePoint libraries and on each update a new major version is created.

I know the maximum number of major version possible is 400,000 in SP2013 for example but to avoid running out of space, we store only the last 10 major versions.

So with these major versions increasing automatically, how far can we go ?
I am wondering what is the limit for version number in SharePoint 2013 and Online.

Answer (score 1):

We have a SharePoint 2013 on premise farm and I noticed a file (Size = 5 MB) in document library which has 731 major versions and this file alone has taken 2.9 GB of storage. So I believe it's a good practice to restrict file version as you mentioned to 10 or as per the business requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I think you missed the point of my question. Even if I restrict the versions to a fix number (10 for example) I can still create new versions of the file and the number of the last version increments on each version that is created. I am curious about what is the highest possible number for a version number.

Comment: Wait, how can a file exist with 731 versions in a library with no versioning enabled?

Comment: @JamesLove I have edited my answer. The document library has "Create major versions" selected and "Keep the following number of Major versions" unchecked. sorry for that.